# PHP multiple array while loop with if condition

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am new to PHP, iam trying to color the cells of column4,column7,column9 based on condition which you can see in the IF block,below is my code what i tried,kindly help me to understand how to achieve this. i am using array because i have got more than 80 columns,in below example iam showing only 10 for explaining.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("server","user","password","db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table1");

echo "<table id='table_id' class='mytable'>

<thead>
<tr>
<th class='heading'>Column1</th>
<th class='heading'>Column2</th>
<th class='heading'>Column3</th>
<th class='heading'>Column4</th>
<th class='heading'>Column5</th>
<th class='heading'>Column6</th>
<th class='heading'>Column7</th>
<th class='heading'>Column8</th>
<th class='heading'>Column9</th>
<th class='heading'>Column10</th>
</tr>
</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$colorfields = array($row['Column4'],$row['Column7'],$row['Column9']);


if ($colorfields < 195 && $colorfields !='')
$classname = "red"; 
else if($colorfields >= 195 && $colorfields < 199.99)
$classname = "yellow";
else if($colorfields >= 199.99)
$classname = "green";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='normal_cell'>" . $row['Column1']."</td>";
echo "<td class='normal_cell'>" . $row['Column2']."</td>";
echo "<td class='normal_cell'>" . $row['Column3']."</td>";
echo "<td class=".$classname.">". $row['Column4']."</td>";
echo "<td class='normal_cell'>" . $row['Column5']."</td>";
echo "<td class='normal_cell'>" . $row['Column6']."</td>";
echo "<td class=".$classname.">". $row['Column7']."</td>";
echo "<td class='normal_cell'>" . $row['Column8']."</td>";
echo "<td class=".$classname.">". $row['Column9']."</td>";
echo "<td class='normal_cell'>" . $row['Column10']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</tbody>";

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: and what problem you are facing?

Comment: Your code is strange, `$colorfields` is an array, you can't compare it with scalar values like a string or a number. And what are these magic values: 195, 199.99? I think this problem can be solved only with css3 selectors.

Comment: @Anant, i am not getting the expected color for cells wherever the IF condition is true,instead i am getting Green color on all cells.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, i am totally new to PHP, just started learning.

Comment: @davidb  check the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write a function that returns the 'red', 'yellow' or 'green', depending the value that is passed in as an argument.

```
 function class_from_val($val) {
    $classname = '';
    if( $val < 195 && $val !='' ) {
       $classname = 'red';
    } else if( $val >= 195 && $val < 199.99 ) {
       $classname = 'yellow';
    } else if( $val >= 199.99 ) {
       $classname = 'green';
    } else {
      // ? val = ""
    }
    return $classname;
 }
```

Then I'd call the function where I need the classname returned

```
 echo "<td class='normal_cell'>"                        .$row['Column3']."</td>";
 echo "<td class='".class_from_val($row['Column4'])."'>".$row['Column4']."</td>";
 echo "<td class='normal_cell'>"                        .$row['Column5']."</td>";
 echo "<td class='normal_cell'>"                        .$row['Column6']."</td>";
 echo "<td class='".class_from_val($row['Column7'])."'>".$row['Column7']."</td>";
```

Comment: thank you, i am trying your solution, im getting blank page.

Comment: Use echo to output function return value. echo class_from_val($row['Column4'])

Comment: @RavinderReddy: yes, an `echo` could be used. I'm just wondering what the advantage of that is, vs. just concatenating the return from the function into a string that is already being echoed.

Comment: @davidb: There's a semicolon missing on the return statement in the function (my bad). I recommend you enable PHP error reporting.  `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  Also consider setting classname to something other than a zero length string. Either in an `else` when none of the if tests evaluates to TRUE, or initializing $classname to a default value at the top of the function. (i.e. what value do you want for `class=` when none of the conditions are true?)

Comment: @spencer7593, thank you, i tried with the semicolon now, i am getting colors exactly, but the numbers are not visible in the cell, cell color is coming properly.

Comment: @spencer7593, sorry, it is working fine. i forgot to add the variable `.$row['Column7']."</td>";` it is working fine now. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these general principles:

- indent the code and space it
- choose carefully your variable names
- divide and rule *(use functions)*

example:

```
function getClassName($col, $field) {
    if ( !in_array($col, [ 'Column4', 'Column7', 'Column9' ]) || empty($field) )
        return 'normal_cell';

    if ( $field >= 199.99 )
        return 'green';

    if ( $field >= 195 )
        return 'yellow';

    return 'red';
}

$cellFormat = '<td class="%s">%s</td>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach ($row as $col => $field) {
        printf($cellFormat, getClassName($col, $field), $field);
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
```